# my usb is auto mounted to /media/usb0 and unable to paste files

Tags: files, configuration, fstab, checkbox

My usb is auto mounted to /media/usb0 and unable to paste files and can't copy any file to my pendrive.(looks like write protected mode)
please help

This is my alert message I get usb connected:
[image: This is my alert message i get usb connected]

This is Disk -usb edit mount options and /etc/fstab conf file entry:
[image: This is Disk -usb edit mount options and /etc/fstab conf file entry]

please helpusb

Answer (score 0):

It's was happened in my ubuntu machine also.i just unmount the /media/usb0 and then mount it in someother ( /home/uname/Desktop/mount )  directory.

## sudo umount /media/usb0

## sudo mount /dev/sda2  /home/uname/Desktop/mount